# array group by in php or count array by group by

Tags: php

i have an array like  :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => b
            [5] => c
            [6] => b
        )
 )
```

so i have to make  array by group by with count total no. of array   like (output) :

```
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 2
```

if array `a` is use two times than count of `a` will be `2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :

```
array_count_values(array)
```

Ex:

```
<?php
$a=array("Cat","Dog","Horse","Dog");
print_r(array_count_values($a));
?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 [Horse] => 1 )
```

Comment: +1 - nice and simple if one knows there is a function in PHP for this.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste code,

```
<?php
$rt=Array(Array('a','a','b','b','c','c'));
$out=array_count_values( $rt[0]);
print_r($out) ;
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
 [a] => 2
 [b] => 2
 [c] => 2
)
```